# How to display the information from a textarea comment box onto the current html page

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I am trying to basically take the information my user is putting into my comment box and then simply input it below that box.

Like a simple comment box that shows the username and the comment of that person below it.

Just on the same starting `index.html` page is fine not trying to send it to a server or anything like that.

What would be the easiest way to do this with javaScript?

I have tried getting `document.getElementByID()` of the whole form, and then doing submit but its not working?

Comment: Do you mean update the input below the textbox live as they type, or after they press a button?

Comment: after they press a button

Comment: I added an additional snippet using a button

Answer (score 3):

You put an ID on the input element and then you can get the information with `element.value`

Below is an example: any text you type in the input field will be copied over to the div

```js
document.getElementById("input").addEventListener("input", e => {
  document.getElementById("output").innerText = e.target.value;
});
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
<input id="input"></input>
```

And an example if they press a button

```js
function foo() {
  document.getElementById("output").innerText = document.getElementById("input").value;
}
```

```html
<input id="input"></input>
<div id="output"></div>
<button onclick="foo()">Copy text</button>
```

Comment: You should use `innerText` instead of `innerHTML` in this case.

Comment: True, I thought it didn't really matter here. I should use `innerText` for the sake of best practices

Comment: Well, without it, if you type `<script>` in the input, nothing shows up.

Comment: You'll probably want to include a regex to replace all line-breaks with `<br>` tags too, as the output div won't respect them unless you use `white-space: pre;` or a `<pre></pre>`. Here's the regex I used: `.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '<br>')`

Comment: If you use `innerText` the `<br>` tags get added automatically, if you use `innerHTML` they don't

Comment: @Jannes Carpentier nifty! I didn't know that. It also appears to automatically remove any instances of multiple spaces in the text. That may be a preference of some, so that's a nice feature too, but if you want to retain multiple spaces, you may need to resort to `innerHTML` and regex, or using `white-space: pre;` in CSS. Not a bad solution either.

Answer (score 0):

You can pull the `.value` of the textarea into whichever element you target. One important note to make is that, because HTML elements don't respect line breaks as actual line breaks in their text content, you'll probably want to include a quick regex to replace all line breaks with `<br>` tags, and another regex to replace every instance of multiple spaces with multiple `&nbsp;` spaces to retain multiple spaces.

Alternatively, if you want to avoid any of the regex replacing, you can simply apply the CSS property `white-space: pre;` to whatever element you're outputting the text into and it will respect whatever spacing is passed into it, whether it be line-breaks or multiple spaces between words.

#### 1. Here's an example **(with regex)**:

```js
const textarea = document.querySelector('textarea');
const div = document.querySelector('div');
textarea.addEventListener('input', function(e) {
    div.innerHTML = e.target.value.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '<br>').replace(/  +/g, m => " " + Array(m.length).join('&nbsp;'));
});
```

```css
html {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 20px;
    height: inherit;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body > * {
    position: relative;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    width: calc(50% - 10px);
    height: 100%;
    padding: 20px;
    border-width: 0;
    background-color: #ccc;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<textarea></textarea>
<div></div>
```

CodePen interactive example: https://codepen.io/brandonmcconnell/pen/2177e440bb55f5a7f035ebcd315a1bdf

---

#### 2. Here is the same example **(with `white-space: pre;`, no regex)**:

```js
const textarea = document.querySelector('textarea');
const div = document.querySelector('div');
textarea.addEventListener('input', function(e) {
    div.innerHTML = e.target.value;
});
```

```css
html {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 20px;
    height: inherit;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body > * {
    position: relative;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    width: calc(50% - 10px);
    height: 100%;
    padding: 20px;
    border-width: 0;
    background-color: #ccc;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
div {
    white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<textarea></textarea>
<div></div>
```

CodePen interactive example: https://codepen.io/brandonmcconnell/pen/0be96bb4ec0168deda587328180cca86